# Menu property for composer block

Tags: menu, episerver

Composer tab needs to have a block with a Menu Property. Is there an inbuild menu property in episerver 6 R2 or do I need to create a custom property for that? What do you suggest? Thanks
I am thinking of PropertyMultipleValue that would contain values for the menu items which I can then integrate with specific design for menu, would that work?

Comment: Nope, no such built-in property.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a **LinkItemCollection** property to select pages that should be included in the menu, if you need to set the menu items explicitly.